# Anaconda Navigator won't open

Tags: python, anaconda

I've accidentally changed my windows 10 user account into non-administrative account, then tried to launch anaconda navigator using the icon not the anaconda prompt and it said I don't have admin permissions, I got everything back to where it was (means that my user account is an admin account) but the navigator still won't launch, and this error is shown :

> An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up
>
> ```
> Main Error 'root_prefix' Traceback  (most recent call last):    File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py",
> ```
>
> line 75, in exception_handler  return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py",
>   line 151, in start_app window = run_app(splash)    File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line
>   65, in run_app window = MainWindow(splash=splash, tab_project=False)
>   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py",
>   line 168, in **init** self.api = AnacondaAPI()
>
> File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py",
>   line 2337, in AnacondaAPI ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()    File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py",
>   line 89, in **init** self._conda_api = CondaAPI()    File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py",
>   line 1767, in CondaAPI CONDA_API = _CondaAPI()    File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py",
>   line 350, in **init** self.set_conda_prefix(info=get_conda_info())
>   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py",
>   line 505, in set_conda_prefix self.ROOT_PREFIX = info['root_prefix']

any one has any idea how to solve it ? it runs on the anaconda propmt thought.
I tried change the shortcut target but it didn't work
Using the last version on Anconda and Windows 10

edit : 
when I launch it from anaconda prompt it launches put display these errors:
edit, when it opens from anaconda prompt it displays those errors:

> ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/api/videos
>
> 2019-02-22 20:36:48,227 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/api/webinars
>
> 2019-02-22 20:36:48,551 - ERROR download_api._download:234 Invalid url
>   https://www.anaconda.com/api/events

and when I launch Jupiter, it doesn't launch

Answer (score 0):

This error can be solved like this, if you are using Linux:

1. Run `cd /root/anaconda3/bin`
2. Run `jupyter-lab --allow-root`
3. You see something like this

> [I 09:44:42.637 LabApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 0 kernels found
>
> [I 09:44:42.886 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from
>   /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
>
> [I 09:44:42.886 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
>   /root/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
>
> [I 09:44:43.136 LabApp] [nb_conda] enabled
>
> [I 09:44:43.193 LabApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
>
> [W 09:44:43.193 LabApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module
>   named 'nbbrowserpdf'
>
> [I 09:44:43.587 LabApp] sparkmagic extension enabled!
>
> [W 09:44:43.587 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled,
>   manually loading...
>
> [I 09:44:43.591 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from
>   /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
>
> [I 09:44:43.591 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
>   /root/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
>
> [I 09:44:43.591 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory:
>   /root/anaconda3/bin
>
> [I 09:44:43.591 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
>
> [I 09:44:43.592 LabApp]
>   http://localhost:8888/?token=d6a066d1346abee2b8cd74cb0857bd685b9be84ead07b305

4. Open a browser and type: http://localhost:8888/?token=d6a066d1346abee2b8cd74cb0857bd685b9be84ead07b305

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10,

1. Uninstall anaconda and download the latest version from the [Anaconda distribution 
   website](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).
2. Install the latest version in your preferred directory.
3. Open up your anaconda prompt and move to the directory where you installed it.
4. Type the command activate root and then anaconda-navigator to launch the navigator.
5. If in case you come along 'Access denied' message showing up in the anaconda prompt, visit this [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8510).
   I hope this helps.